# How to Secure Membase?

Tags: membase

Once a membase server is setup, any machine can connect to it via the ip plus port. How to secure membase such that it will only listen to specific ip addresses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to do this through the use of a firewall, either local to the Membase server or as part of your overall environment.  Like Memcached, Membase also supports SASL authentication to control access to a particular dataset, but that's not meant to be a security measure.